# Traveling Wave Solution of Bistable Diffusion Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I would like some help understanding a proof regarding the existence of traveling wave solutions to the equation
$$u_t = u_{xx} + f(u),$$
where $f(u)$ is assumed to be continuously differentiable. We seek solutions of the form $u(x,t) = v(x-ct) = v(\eta)$ that tend to different constant values, i.e  $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} u(x,t) = a^{\pm}$. Substituting $v(\eta)$ into the PDE, we arrive at the system of first order equations \begin{align*}
\dot{v}_1 &= v_2 \\
\dot{v}_2 &=  -f(v_1)-cv_2
\end{align*}
Since $\lim_{\eta \to \pm \infty} v = a^{\pm}$, we expect $a^{\pm}$ to be fixed points of the system. This implies that $f(a^{\pm}) = 0$. If we calculate the Jacobian of the system evaluated at one of these fixed points, we find that the eigenvalues satisfy $$\lambda = \frac{-c \pm \sqrt{c^2 - 4f'(a^{\pm})}}{2}. $$
The textbook I'm reading asserts that in order for the traveling wave solution to exist, we need $f'(a^{\pm}) \leq 0$, so that each fixed point is a saddle. I understand that two different saddle points can connect trajectories, but why can't say $(a^{-},0)$ be an unstable node and $(a^{+},0)$ be a stable node? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What book are you reading? I would indeed impose that $f'(a^-) \geq 0$ and $f'(a^+) \leq 0$.

Comment: Just a comment passing by. Maybe the reason behind this is related to physics? Note that if you have source-sink connection, you must have uncountably many connecting trajectories. From point of view of original problem it means that there is a continuum of different travelling waves with the same velocity.